# Splitting the string and sorting - Linq

Tags: linq, split

I have a list "Sites" with one of the items as "Year". It is defined as a string and is in the format "MM/yyyy". 
Data for "Year" is

```
01/2012
04/2012
01/2013
06/2012
```

I understand that I can use `DateTime.Parse` to convert the string and sort it. But I want to split the string and do the sort using linq. Is there a possibility of splitting the MM and yyyy, sorting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as indicated in the other answer, you can do it. My answer use an anonymous struct instead so the sorting should be more efficient.

`method1Result` show what I would have done (assuming that the data is always valid). The main advantage is that you have `DateTime` object so it would be easier to use afterward.

`method2Result` do not use `DateTime.Parse` as required in the question. However, it lead to longer code and the result is less usable (and if you need to return it, you would have to replace anonymous struct by one you define.

```
var data = new string[]
{
    "01/2012",
    "04/2012",
    "01/2013",
    "06/2012",
};

var method1Result = data
    .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x);

var method2Result = data
    .Select(x => 
        { 
            var t = x.Split('/'); 
            return new { 
                year = int.Parse(t[1]), 
                month = int.Parse(t[0]) }; 
            })
    .OrderBy(x => x.year)
    .ThenBy(x => x.month);
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, this can be easily done. However, this is inefficient, because you would have to do a split on each comparison:

```
.OrderBy(yearMonthStr => {
    var tokens = yearMonthStr.Split('/');
    return int.Parse(tokens[0]) + 100*int.Parse(tokens[1])
})
```